# In UWP C# Reunion Desktop App, how can I access sensor metadata like Model (DEVPKEY_Sensor_Model)?

Tags: c#, uwp, sensors

I've created a desktop C# app using the reunion aka Windows App SDK nuget packages and I am able to access my CustomSensor(s) thought the Sensor API and read sensor samples and some sensor properties. However I'm interested in also reading the sensor specific properties like Model (DEVPKEY_Sensor_Model), is this possible through the UWP CustomSensor API?

Comment: Maybe [CustomSensorReading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.sensors.custom.customsensorreading?view=winrt-20348)?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but like I mentioned I am able to read sensor samples, but those read-only properties are not part of the underlying HID message hence not included in the CustomSensorReading properties.

Comment: Have you tried to use the device enumeration and check the [DeviceInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation?view=winrt-20348) to see if this could help you get the metadata?

Comment: I should have mentioned that I have tried the obvious property collections in both DeviceInformation and CustomSensorReading, they do not contain the full set of properties available through the Win32 API like Model, Manufacturer and Friendly Name